# Ruby-mp3info album artwork

Tags: ruby, mp3

I have this gem working such that I can change the id3 data for a given song. However I need to also be able to add album artwork to the song. I have the artwork at a given URL. How do I go about this?

```
Mp3Info.open(file.path) do |mp3|
  mp3.tag.title  = title
  mp3.tag.artist = artist
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems ruby-mp3info only supports text frames at the moment, see here: https://github.com/moumar/ruby-mp3info/blob/v0.7.1/lib/mp3info/id3v2.rb#L319

Using [taglib-ruby](http://robinst.github.com/taglib-ruby/), it would work like this:

```
require 'taglib'
require 'open-uri'

picture_data = open(picture_url).read

TagLib::MPEG::File.open(file.path) do |file|
  tag = file.id3v2_tag

  pic = TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame.new
  pic.picture = picture_data
  pic.mime_type = "image/jpeg"
  pic.type = TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame::FrontCover

  tag.add_frame(pic)
  file.save
end
```

Comment: for mp3 should I use TagLib::MP3::File.open etc..

or does MPEG do essentially the same thing?

Comment: There is no TagLib::MP3, see [the API documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/taglib-ruby/frames). The API is the same as in [taglib](http://taglib.github.com/), where the file classes exist for each file format (which then can hold tags for individual tag formats).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stuck with mp3Info gem, try using id3Lib, http://id3lib-ruby.rubyforge.org/. From my experience, that one's better.

not sure about this, but try reading the file and setting it directly to

mp3.tag2.APIC

Answer (score 0):

Using ruby-mp3info you can add artwork:

From the [documentation](http://github.com/moumar/ruby-mp3info):

```
file = File.new('input_img','rb')
Mp3Info.open '1.mp3' do |m|
  m.tag2.add_picture(file.read)
end
```